# Unable to trigger function from onFailure

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

While reading the tutorial for LDAP Authentication from [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_05_Using_LDAP_Login_Module_to_authenticate_user_with_LDAP_server.pdf) and messing around with it's relevant sample code from [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/LDAPLoginModuleProject.zip), i see that there is a function to handle login failures in the WL.Client.invokeProcedure. (***UPDATE : Nope, onFailure is not used to handle login failures***).

In the sample, both onSuccess and onFailure calls the same functions. I modified the onFailure  portion to call another function if the LDAP login fails.
The onSuccess portion works fine but the onFailure never gets called. Instead, the password field just goes blank and neither does the console print the error message i created.

I am not sure why this is happening, is there something else that needs to be configured ?

Here's the code from LDAPApp.js :

```
function getSecretData(){
    WL.Logger.debug("@getSecretData");

    var invocationData = {
            adapter: "DummyAdapter",
            procedure: "getSecretData_Success",
            parameters: []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess: getSecretData_Callback_Success,
        onFailure: getSecretData_Callback_Fail,
        invocationContext: {}
    });
}

function getSecretData_Callback_Success(response){
    var UserName = WL.Client.getLoginName("LDAPRealm");
    $("#resultDiv").html(new Date() + "<hr/>");
    $("#resultDiv").append("Secret data :: " + response.invocationResult.loginStatus + " " + UserName);
}

function getSecretData_Callback_Fail(response){
    WL.Logger.error("Error place");
    $("#resultDiv").html(new Date() + "<hr/>");
    $("#resultDiv").append("Fail !! :: " + response.invocationResult.secretData);
}
```

Here's the code from the adapter, DummyAdapter-impl.js:

```
function getSecretData_Success(){
    WL.Logger.debug("@getSecretData_Success");

    return {loginStatus: "1_Login Success ! "};
}

function getSecretData_Fail(){

    WL.Logger.debug("@getSecretData_Fail");
    return {secretData: "Login Fail !"};
}
```

**Update 26th May'14** : onFailure is not for detecting login failures. You will get challenged again which, in my case will happen in the LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge portion. It will be up to the individual to handle these errors. Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: AFSIK onFailure() function will execute whenever timeout occurs or some procedure error. You cant have failure function in Adapter. Also if your login failed means you will get challenge again.

Comment: Hmm...so, is there anyway to capture that the login failed ? I would like to display an appropriate error message.

Comment: you will get challenge again in your challenge handler right?

Comment: Yes that is correct....ok, i believe i can find out a workaround for this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant have failure function in adapter AFAIK.

```
`The failure handler of this call is called in two cases:

The procedure was called but failed. In this case, the invocationResult property is added to the response received by the failure handler. This property has the same structure as the invocationResult property returned to the success handler, but the value of the isSuccessful attribute is false. For the structure of the invocationResult property, see invocationResult.
A technical failure resulted in the procedure not being called. In this case, the failure handler receives a standard response object.`
```

[via](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html)